# How do I properly move a seek pointer in a file with stdio in C

Tags: c, file, random-access

I'm messing around with seek pointers in C, and my exercise is to write a database (format: ID NAME SURNAME AGE) into a textfile.
So everything works fine (saving new data etc.) but I can't find a solution on how to delete a line in my textfile.

```
void cut_from_file(char* filename, int start, int stop) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    fpos_t position;
    fseek(fp, 34, SEEK_SET);
    fputs("Hello world", fp);
    fclose (fp);
}
```

Note: I want to make it somehow a random access file.

So my question would be how can I move the filepointer let's say 34 characters forward and overwrite the characters on that position but leave the characters from position 0 - 33 as they are?

If I try to do it like on my test function above I overwrite everything from offset 0 - 33 with '/00' and on position 34 is Hello World.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wrote that function to test how I could 'jump' lines in my text file. But I still have the same issue if I add that if condition

Comment: ... which is ok, because this should be minimal :)

Answer (score 3):

fopen(filename, "r+") was the answer, gosh I messed that up pretty hard.

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `SEEK_CUR` instead of `SEEK_SET` to move forward from the currect index. `SEEK_SET` takes you 34 chars forward from the beginning of the file. Also "w" in opening the file overwrites all its contents.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of simply making a chunk of the file disappear.

The two possible solutions that I can see are:

1. Read the whole file in, write it out and skip the line(s) you want to delete.
2. Use an extra byte (and fixed-width records!) to indicate if an entry is "deleted" or "not deleted". That means deleting a record is a single write and you then know you can re-use the space for another record.

Comment: Yeah I know about that, but I am not allowed to do the first solution :) I'll think about how to erase it properly.

Answer (score 0):

To delete one line from the file, you could open a temporary file and write the contents to it line by line, and then skip the line you want to delete, later you can replace the original file with the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Move the last entry to the entry you want to delete.  (2) Call [truncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate) to shorten the file.